# Bitcoin-qt database for BitcoinJ downloadBlockChain()

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, bitcoinj

I am using bitcoinJ to develop a bitcoin based payment module for my project. I have the complete block chain downloaded/in sync with the network on the bitcoin-qt client.
Is there a way I can use this bitcoin-qt blockchain database in my bitcoinJ application rather than waiting downloadBlockChain() method which is taking a huge amount of time.

PS : Any pointers on how long will it take downloadBlockChain() to complete the download?

Comment: It might easily take a couple of days.

Comment: @Lohoris Thanks. Just one quick question :If I use saveWalletToFile, the blockchain too gets saved, right?

Comment: No, it only saves the wallet, which is were your coins are saved.

Comment: So it means every other time when I have to make a payment, the blockchain has to be downloaded all over again?

Comment: No of course, just don't delete it.